# Can i use "Append to Array variable" inside ApplyToEach which have concurrency enable

Tags: power-automate, power-platform

I am initializing 2 array variables inside my power automate flow, when a SharePoint item is modified:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1711119773948.png]

then i am getting SharePoint list items, ApplyToEach on them, and inside each ApplyToEach iteration i am calling a child flow then append values to the 2 arrays based on the result of the child flow + value of the Apply to each, as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1711119907707.png]

then after completing the ApplyToEach, i need to do some operations on the 2 array values.

now the "Concurrency control" is disabled inside the ApplyToEach:-

[image: johnjohnPter_2-1711119961548.png]

so is it fine if i enable it? for example to set it to 5? will it work with calling child flows and appending array variables based on the child flow result and based on the apply to each item value? or this might cause issues?

Comment: Does it work at the minute because concurrency control off means that it runs concurrently, you’re just not telling it how many at a time. If you want to control the concurrency, that’s when you flick that switch.

Comment: @Skin can you advice more on what you mean by "does it work at the minute"?

Comment: @Skin also  think by default it operates sequentially

Comment: Interesting, I just tested and yes, you're right.  I've had situations before where I've had to turn concurrency to 1 because the order of the items from the original array have come out differently with concurrency control turned off.  I've been doing this for a long time and have never tested a basic array before to prove the concept but yes, you appear to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and saying that **yes**, it's fine to set the concurrency control to **On**.

I tested with two flows, one looked like this ...

[image: Flow]

... the other **without** the random delay and in both cases, the concurrency control was set to 20.

The original array of data looked like this ...

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
```

These were the results ...

**Scenario 1 (with random delay between 1 and 10 seconds)**

```
[
  3,
  19,
  7,
  13,
  6,
  2,
  14,
  17,
  11,
  10,
  8,
  5,
  9,
  1,
  12,
  15,
  18,
  4,
  16,
  20
]
```

**Scenario 2 (without delay)**

```
[
  6,
  15,
  5,
  1,
  8,
  4,
  3,
  12,
  17,
  2,
  7,
  16,
  13,
  9,
  20,
  11,
  14,
  10,
  19,
  18
]
```

In both cases, the `New Array` variable still held all values, not missing anything.

I would think this would be the best way to test as well given it's doing very little compared to running off and taking a different time per child flow execution given levels of complexity, etc.

To be completely frank, I wouldn't expect Microsoft to create a non thread safe implementation for the concurrency functionality in PA so I guess this kinda proves it.

Comment: and i tested this on my end , and all the items representing the array were created , i tested on concurrency of 3 and of 5